# Trying to understand projection onto a plane, subspace of R^3, of a point b when there is no solution for Ax = b

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, projection

I was following along some online classes for linear algebra and was doing fine until it came to projections onto subspaces and I really really could not understand the proof and logic behind the given formula to complete the projection.

So I am aware that if my problem was practical and I just wanted to solve the projection I could use the formula which is easy to implement and compute, but the problem is I want to understand it and I can't. So my approach is I decided I would attempt it from scratch and forget about the formula so that I could try to come up with a solution for doing the projection myself. I limited myself to R^3 projecting onto a plane subspace because that is most easy for me to picture in terms of geometry and I suspect generalizing to higher dimensions would be much much harder. So here is what I did:

We start with any two **independent** vectors spanning a plane in R^3. We turn them into unit vectors (normalize).

$$ V_1 = \frac{V_1}{|V_1|}; V_2 = \frac{V_2}{|V_2|} \in \Bbb R^3$$

And the problem is we have a vector ***b*** which is outside of the plane spanned by V1 and V2. We want to find the best projection of ***b*** onto the plane spanned by V1 and V2, which we call ***p***, such that the difference ***|b-p|*** is minimized.

We take the cross product to find a third vector going "upwards" (from the plane)

$$ V_3 = \frac{V_1 \times V_2}{|V_1 \times V_2|}$$

Then we take the cross product between V1 and V3 to find a "better V2" to complete an orthonormal basis in R^3

$$V_2^* = \frac{V_1 \times V_3}{|V_1 \times V_3|}$$

We dump the vectors into a transformation matrix *A*

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} V_1 & V_2^* & V_3 \end{bmatrix}$$

Now I can transform the vector ***b*** by the inverse of ***A*** such that it is "tilted" into a distorted space where I can "pretend" that V1 and V2 span a plane perfectly aligned with the standard vector axis (1, 0, 0) and (0, 1, 0), and the up vector is actually up (0, 0, 1).

$$ b^* = A^{-1} \cdot b$$

And then, by ignoring the "extra" component of ***b**** I can transform the vector "back" to the original coordinates to find the projection. But the problem is I don't know how to generate this "half-assed identity matrix" such that it discards exactly the same component I made up with the cross product pointing away from the plane. What I mean is this:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot b^*$$

Because by ignoring the made-up component I am basically projecting the point onto the plane *as if* the plane was perfectly aligned with the other two axes and there was no "distortion" on the space, so that the projection of ***b*** onto the plane is simply found by ignoring the extra component which brings it outside of the plane. (I truly don't know if this makes sense I am just starting with linear algebra, please let me know if I am talking non-sense). And then you transform the projection "back to the original coordinate system" by multiplying it with ***A*** (since ***A*** is the matrix which brings the standard axis vectors (1, 0, 0) and (0, 1, 0) back to the basis spanning $c_1*V_1 + c_2*V_2^*$).

The complete solution I came up with to workout the projection ***p*** $ \in \Bbb R^2 $ of ***b*** $ \in \Bbb R^3 $ is:

$$ p = A \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot (A^{-1} \cdot b)$$

I have no idea how to manipulate these variables in a way which I could generate that "almost identity" matrix on the fly without needing to hardcode it in. And I also have no idea if any of what I said above makes sense or if it is all idiotic, I just know I plugged this into a python code and compared it with the results from WolframAlpha (there is the command "project vector b onto {v1, v2}") and the results always match 100%.

Edit: I just found some cases when my results don't match. They match most of the time I haven't understood why some don't. But I just noticed that if b is a vector (0, 0, anything) it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is a very nice start. I would summarize the steps you are taking as follows:

1. Write everything in a basis where your plane $p$ is the x-y plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$
2. Use a projection map to map $b$ to the x-y plane.
3. Do the inverse change of basis to get back to the original basis.

This method works, but as you noted it requires you to 'hard code' the projection map to the x-y plane. So how could we refine your technique to get a co-ordinate independent formula? Well suppose we are working in the co-ordinates where $p$ is the x-y plane. Then the vertical component of $b$ is given by the dot product with $(0,0,1)$: $(b \cdot e_3)e_3$ (where $e_3 = (0,0,1)$) right? So if we want to get rid of the vertical component we can define $b' = b - (b\cdot e_3)e_3.$ This formula gives you the result of the "half-assed identity", which could more properly be called the "projection to the x-y plane".

Now in the general case, instead of transforming to new co-ordinates and taking the dot product with $e_3$, we can simply take the dot product with our normal vector (the one going 'upwards' from the plane) which you called $V_3$. So the projection formula would be $b' = b - (b\cdot V_3) V_3$.

Comment: Thank you. I still haven't completely understood it to the level of detail I wish I had but I will think about your suggestions a bit more. But it is good to know that I wasn't completely lost and at least made some sense with my attempt.